# Remove flashing shadow when pressing buttons on mobile device

Tags: css

[image: pressing button]

I'm creating this toggle component but as you can see in the gif whenever I press it on a mobile device there's this flashing shadow behind it, which is probably some native behaviour to indicate the button is being pressed.

I'm trying to get rid of it as it makes the component look kinda clunky and not very smooth. I tried several combinations of props like changing the background color, shadow, transitions, pseudo selectors like `:active` and others, even changing the element from `<button>` to `<div>`, nothing really works and I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi ! Can you share some code so we can try some things ?

Comment: @SebastienServouze I think there's no need for any code, literally any button press on mobile device will produce such shadow, I'm just wondering if it's possible to remove it in any way

Comment: So you think the shadow is not produced by any css ? I think it does. A sample of code always help !